# Profits calculation based on total margin w/variable costs

Tags: excel-formula, calculated-field

So I don't know if my title accurately described my needs, but here goes;

I sell items online. I need to figure out what I should set the Retail price at to come to a specific margin %.

Image of the Sheet I am using

[image]

In this example, I want to hit 20% margin. What formula (Excel) can I use to help me determine that? Keep in mind that the 'Amazon 15%' and the 'Returns 5%' will change when the Retail changes - therein lies my challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a mathematical question instead of an excel question.

But the answer is:

```
=(B2+E2)/(1-(0.15+0.05+0.2))
```

We divide the total of cost by 1 - the sum of the various percentages.

```
        x = COGS + Shipping + 0.15x + 0.05x + 0.20x
        x = COGS + Shipping + 0.40x
x - 0.40x = COGS + Shipping
    0.60x = COGS + Shipping
        x = (COGS + Shipping)/0.60
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the math help!

Comment: If this worked, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Scott, can you help me with a revision?

The Amazon fee is a variable fee. If it is under $200, it remains at 15%. If the retail price is over $200, the first $200 is 15% and the remainder is 10%.